# How to PInvoke SFileFindFirstFile

Tags: c#, pinvoke

The declaration is

```
typedef struct _SFILE_FIND_DATA
{
    char   cFileName[MAX_PATH];         // Full name of the found file
    char * szPlainName;                 // Plain name of the found file
    DWORD  dwHashIndex;                 // Hash table index for the file
    DWORD  dwBlockIndex;                // Block table index for the file
    DWORD  dwFileSize;                  // File size in bytes
    DWORD  dwFileFlags;                 // MPQ file flags
    DWORD  dwCompSize;                  // Compressed file size
    DWORD  dwFileTimeLo;                // Low 32-bits of the file time (0 if not present)
    DWORD  dwFileTimeHi;                // High 32-bits of the file time (0 if not present)
    DWORD  lcLocale;                    // Locale version

} SFILE_FIND_DATA, *PSFILE_FIND_DATA;

HANDLE WINAPI SFileFindFirstFile(HANDLE hMpq, const char * szMask, SFILE_FIND_DATA * lpFindFileData, const char * szListFile)</pre>
```

I tried

```
public unsafe struct SFILE_FIND_DATA
{
    fixed byte cFileName[260];         // Full name of the found file
    byte[] szPlainName;                 // Plain name of the found file
    uint dwHashIndex;                 // Hash table index for the file
    uint dwBlockIndex;                // Block table index for the file
    uint dwFileSize;                  // File size in bytes
    uint dwFileFlags;                 // MPQ file flags
    uint dwCompSize;                  // Compressed file size
    uint dwFileTimeLo;                // Low 32-bits of the file time (0 if not present)
    uint dwFileTimeHi;                // High 32-bits of the file time (0 if not present)
    uint lcLocale;                    // Locale version

}

[DllImport("StormLib.dll")]
public static extern uint SFileFindFirstFile(IntPtr hMpq, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string mask,
    out SFILE_FIND_DATA filedata, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string listfile);
```

Is this right? It doesn't error but it doesn't return what it should.

Comment: What does it return and what do you expect it to return?

Comment: Does it work if you change `byte[] szPlainName` to `IntPtr szPlainName`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`szPlainName` shouldn't be `byte[]` - how does the runtime know how big the array is? Try this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public unsafe struct SFILE_FIND_DATA
{
    fixed byte cFileName[260];         // Full name of the found file
    string szPlainName;                 // Plain name of the found file
    uint dwHashIndex;                 // Hash table index for the file
    uint dwBlockIndex;                // Block table index for the file
    uint dwFileSize;                  // File size in bytes
    uint dwFileFlags;                 // MPQ file flags
    uint dwCompSize;                  // Compressed file size
    uint dwFileTimeLo;                // Low 32-bits of the file time (0 if not present)
    uint dwFileTimeHi;                // High 32-bits of the file time (0 if not present)
    uint lcLocale;                    // Locale version
}
```

Comment: Did you try it or are you just guessing?

Comment: How can I try it if I don't have the code to the function? What, is it wrong?